# Problems with GD::Graph:: Line and trying to replace the Perl Module with better option

Tags: perl

I am trying to create few graphs in Perl running on windows. I used GD::Graph but the quality of the image and graph is poor. If i try to increase the W and H of the graph then Axis labels look very different.

```
my $graph = GD::Graph::lines->new(800, 300);
  $graph->set( 
  x_label           => 'ABC',
  y_label           => 'DEF',
  title             => "ABC_DEF",
  y_max_value       => 100,
  x_max_value       => 0,
  x_tick_number     => 10,
  x_label_skip      => 1,
  y_tick_number     => 10,
  y_label_skip      => 1,
  box_axis          => 0,
  line_width        => 3,
  labelclr          => 'black',
  axislabelclr      => 'black',
  legendclr         => 'black', 
  valuesclr         => 'black', 
  textclr           => 'black',  

      ) or die $graph->error;
      $graph->set_legend(@rates_rec); 
$graph->set_x_label_font('/fonts/arial.ttf' ,24);
$graph->set_y_label_font('/fonts/arial.ttf',24);
$graph->set_x_axis_font('/fonts/arial.ttf',24);
$graph->set_y_axis_font('/fonts/arial.ttf',24);
$graph->set_values_font('/fonts/arial.ttf',24);  
$graph->set_title_font('/fonts/arial.ttf', 24);
$graph->set_legend_font(gdTinyFont);
$graph->set_legend_font('/fonts/arial.ttf', 24);
```

For some reason setting the Font size for different labels axes don't seem to be working. 
I was looking into different options. and came across Google::Charts but have no Idea how to use it.

MY final output would be a image file which I am linking it into a word file. Any help with Embedding the final image file into word would also be helpful.

I would appreciate for some Perl Module suggestions to create high quality chart images. and embedded them into MS Word file.

Please do reply back,

Answer (score 0):

I use GD::Graph on WinXP with ActiveState 5.8.8.  My font specs do not include the /fonts/ part, I just have $graph->set...font('arial', 24).  Works great.